# Trigger active class of parent link when on child link page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the javascript code below to put my parent menu item to class active when I'm on the page for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ it works. But I also wanna put the parent menu item to class active when I'm at the subpages/child menu item like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/, may I know how to do that?

Example I'm at this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/, how to I get the URL like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/, without the /ask so that I can have the parent menu item (question) to be in active class when I'm at the child page of question which is (ask).

The code below only works if I'm at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/, but if I'm at the child page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/, parent link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/) doesn't change to active class.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="/"><h5>Home</h5></a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="/online/" class="dropdown-toggle " role="button" aria-expanded="false"><h5>Online<span class="caret"></span></h5></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="/online/history/">History</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/online/science/">Science</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/online/math">Mathematics</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/online/english/">English</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>



<script type="text/javascript">

 var url = window.parent.location.href;
      $('ul.nav a[href="'+ url +'"]').parent().addClass('active');

      $('ul.nav a').filter(function() {
        return this.href == url;
      }).parent().addClass('active');



</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parents()` to match the parent and all ancestors. Give it a selector argument to restrict to just the `li` tags.

```
$('ul.nav a').filter(function() {
    return this.href == url;
}).parents('li').addClass('active');
```